# Django partial index on date

Tags: django, django-models

Django has allowed partial indices for a while now. I’ve seen examples where it’s set on boolean and strings, but what if I want to set it on a date, for example > 01-01-2023? Engine is PostgreSQL.

Comment: I don't think it is any different. Have you tried something like `condition=Q(created_at__gt=datetime.date(2023, 1, 1))`?

Comment: @Selcuk - this does seem to work, as in Django makemigrations and migrate succeed. Do you want to do an answer so I can pick it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason it wouldn't be supported for dates. I haven't tried it myself but this should work:

```
condition=Q(created_at__gt=datetime.date(2023, 1, 1))
```